# Day of Quarter in Redshift

Tags: amazon-redshift

I'm trying to create a calculation based on days in a quarter. Problem is, I just can't find anything on how to do it that's similar to how you would do day of year.

```
SELECT
event_date,
day_of_quarter
FROM table_a
WHERE event_date BETWEEN '2018-10-01' AND '2019-03-31'
```

So in the above example for `day_of_quarter`, `2018-10-01` would retun `1`, `2018-12-31` would return `92` and say, `2019-03-05` would return `5`

Comment: You can use something like `event_date - date_trunc('quarter', event_date)`

Answer (score 3):

Here is the SQL for this

```
SELECT
event_date,
(event_date - date_trunc('quarter', event_date)::date)+1 day_of_quarter
FROM table_a
WHERE event_date BETWEEN '2018-10-01' AND '2019-03-31'
```

just `event_date - date_trunc('quarter', event_date)` gives a day before, thus `+1`

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
ABS(DATEDIFF(DAY, event_date, DATE_TRUNC('quarter', event_date)) ) + 1 AS DAY_OF_QUARTER
```